# How do I insert into MySql database with select statement using Laravel 7 from two different connections?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to copy the data from one database to another database on a different server. The databases are identical in structure. From searching around I have tried using the insertUsing() method in Laravel.

```
$new_connection = DB::connection('mysql2');
```

```
//Insert Using requires an array of columns
$column_list = Schema::getColumnListing('users');

//This is my select statement
$select = $new_connection->table('users')->select('*');

//This is my insert statement
DB::table('users')->insertUsing($column_list,$select);
```

This doesn't produce any errors but no data is being inserted into the table.
If I have identical data in the database I am copying to, I get an error saying the primary key already exists so I know it is reading the data from the other server.

Is there another way of getting this done?

Comment: What's wrong with just using `insert()`? I don't see any mention of `insertUsing()` in [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries). Though really this is probably better done on the command line using a `mysqldump | mysql` pipe.

Comment: @miken32 from the source "Insert new records into the table using a subquery."

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice you weren't doing a `get()` on the old database records. I think you'll find the problem is that a subquery won't be able to use a separate database connection.

Comment: @miken32 I could do an insert but not sure how I would do that if I am copying the full database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subqueries such as those used by `insertUsing` won't be able to use a separate database. There's no underlying limitation, it's just that Laravel doesn't use database prefixes when building queries. So if your databases are on the same server you could do this by building a raw query like this:

```php
DB::insert("INSERT INTO mysql1.users SELECT * FROM mysql2.users");
```

Another option is pulling the data from one DB and inserting it into the other. Assuming you have a fairly large table, you should use chunking to ensure you don't load the entire table into memory.

If you are moving from the "mysql2" connection to your default connection it might look like this:

```php
$users1 = DB::table('users');
$users2 = DB::connection('mysql2')->table('users');
$page = 0;
$size = 50;
while (true) {
    // get some records
    $users = $users2->skip($page * $size)->take($size)->get();
    // end the loop when there are no more results
    if ($users->count() === 0) {
        break;
    }
    // convert the results and each row to an array
    $user_array = $users->map(fn ($u) => (array)$u)->toArray();
    // save them into the new database
    $users1->insert($user_array);
    // increment the page for the next iteration
    $page++;
}
```

I'd recommend using proper tools such as `mysqldump` to do this though.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I don't think the raw query would work since those prefixes represent the database name, not the connection. The other option would work out though, I will try that if I can't get the other query working.

Comment: After trying the second option I am getting an error, Argument 1 must be of type array, object given.

Comment: toArray() doesn't exist anymore in Laravel 6+

Comment: Yes if the other connection is on a different server altogether then there's no way to do that. `insert()` takes arrays so you should use `toArray()` on the collection result and its children. Answer updated.

Comment: I assure you they are not going to remove `toArray()` from Laravel. It would break everything.